# Screen Size on emulator is too big on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

When I open my project, the window of the emulator is just fine. the actual "phone" is half hidden under my UI. Scaling in the run config doesn't help the situation.
**The picture is the emulator already running.
What the issue looks like.
[Picture of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulxfB.png)

Comment: have you tried the free genymotion simulator it does not have issues like that and is much faster

Comment: Us the little magnifying glass to change the zoom.

Comment: I have the same error... did you find how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

go to AVD and edit in Device Frame set a Skin
[image: image for reference]

Answer (score -1):

You can disable the "Scale display to real size" flag after starting the virtual device. helped in my case.

Comment: Where would I find that?

Comment: There is a  dialog box "Launch Options" right after starting the Device.

Comment: Mine just asks me to choose a device aka which emulator and nothing more after pressing 'run' on my program.